# user privilege system in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

[image: user privilege to menus]

I have populate this from menu & sub_menu table. now i want to provide individually access to particular user via checkbox selection. if checked = add privilege, if unchecked = remove privilege through loop in bulk.

Can someone please provide help to make database structure to store access details? and update (if checked) & delete (if unchecked) process.

What i have tried :

User.table :

```
 id  | Name
 1   | test
```

menu.table :

```
id | name
1  |  User
2  |  Category
```

submenu.table

```
 id | name            | menu_id
 1  |  Add User       | 1
 2  |  User List      | 1
 3  |  Category List  | 2
```

menu_assign.table

```
id  | menu_id  |  sub_menu_id  | user_id
1   | 1        |  1            | 1
2   | 2        |  3            | 1
```

What i have tried :

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="del[]" value="<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>">
```

Process.php :

```
foreach($_POST['del'] as $mid) {
       if(!in_array($mid, $_POST['menu'])){
                $obj->removeAssignMenu("admin_menu_assign","admin_submenu_id",$mid,"user_id",$id); //DELETE FROM $table WHERE $field = '$id' AND $user = $uid
            }
            header("location:../?page=role_assign&id=".$id);
        }

        foreach($_POST['menu'] as $k){

            $get_main_menu = $obj->selectRequiredRow("admin_submenu", "id", $k); //SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field = '$value'

            $admin_menu_id = $get_main_menu['admin_menu_id'];
            $admin_submenu_id = $get_main_menu['id'];

            $data = array(
                "admin_menu_id" => $admin_menu_id,
                "admin_submenu_id" => $k,
                "user_id" => $id
            );

            $check = $obj->selectMenuAssigned("admin_menu_assign","admin_submenu_id", $admin_submenu_id,"user_id",$id); // SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field = '$value' AND $user = $id

            if (!isset($check['admin_submenu_id'])) {
                $obj->insert("admin_menu_assign", $data);
            } else {
                $obj->editRow("admin_menu_assign", $data, "admin_submenu_id", $check['admin_submenu_id'],"user_id",$id); // UPDATE $table SET $key ="."'$value' "."WHERE $field = '$id'
            }

            header("location:../?page=role_assign&id=".$id);
        }
```

I was able to assign ids in menu_assign table if all is checked but got issues while updating if there is some uncheck and some checked. also that  multiple check box might be checked or might be unchecked so this update or remove privilege should work for both at once (in loop).

Comment: after a `header("location:..");` do `exit();` which means, your redirects need to be in if-statements not just in the loop. You can't redirect more than once! You can't redirect on every iteration of a loop. Its just not possible.

Comment: can you pls provide me foreach loop logic for my condition ? like update or insert row for checked & remove row if unchecked at once.